# UIPageView Controller fade background color transition

Tags: ios, swift3, background-color, uipageviewcontroller

I am using swift 3 and want to use fade color from one view controller background color to another view controller background color (page view controller color transition) 
for example if first page is blue and second page is red when the user scroll to go to the second page the blue transition to red and when the red page cover screen completely the color is red 
I used these code but I received Error

```
UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context: nil)
    UIView.setAnimationDuration(0.80)
    UIView.setAnimationTransition(.flipFromLeft, for: (self.navigationController?.view)!, cache: false)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(self.next as! UIViewController , animated: true)
    UIView.commitAnimations()
```

**Here is all my codes**

```
class pageVC : UIPageViewController , UIPageViewControllerDataSource , UIPageViewControllerDelegate {



let pageVC = UIPageControl()
lazy var VCArr : [UIViewController] = {

    return [self.VCInstance(name : "FirtsVC"),
            self.VCInstance(name : "SecondVC"),
            self.VCInstance(name :"ThirdVC"),
            self.VCInstance(name :"FourthVC"),
            self.VCInstance(name :"FivethVC")]

}()

private func VCInstance(name : String) -> UIViewController {
    return UIStoryboard(name : "Main" , bundle : nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: name)


}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.dataSource = self
    self.delegate = self


    UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context: nil)
    UIView.setAnimationDuration(0.80)
    UIView.setAnimationTransition(.flipFromLeft, for: (self.navigationController?.view)!, cache: false)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(self.next as! UIViewController , animated: true)
    UIView.commitAnimations()

    let launchedBefore = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "launchedBefore")
    if launchedBefore  {
        print("Not first launch!")
        print("Should Launch MainTabBarController!")

        /////Not First Time launch! reach mainTabBarController//////////




    } else {
        print("First launch, setting UserDefault.")
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "launchedBefore")
    }
    //////Lock Rotation/////////
    var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
        return false
    }
    var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return .portrait
    }

    func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        let value =  UIInterfaceOrientation.portrait.rawValue
        UIDevice.current.setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
        UIViewController.attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation()
    }
    func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return [UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait ]
    }
    ///////Lock Roration//////
    if VCArr.first != nil {

        print("first Page Reached!")
    }

    if let firstVC = VCArr.first {
        setViewControllers([firstVC] , direction: .forward , animated: true, completion: nil)

    }


}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    let view = self.pageVC.currentPage
    for view in self.view.subviews {
        if view is UIScrollView {
            let pageVC = UIPageControl()
            self.pageVC.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.lightText
            self.pageVC.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.white
            self.pageVC.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            self.pageVC.numberOfPages = VCArr.count
            self.pageVC.center = self.view.center
            self.view.addSubview(self.pageVC)
            pageVC.layer.position.y = self.view.frame.height - 150;
        }else if view is UIPageControl{
            view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            pageVC.numberOfPages = 5
            pageVC.center = self.view.center
            pageVC.layer.position.y = self.view.frame.height - 100 ;

        }
    }

}




public func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?{
    guard let viewControllerIndex = VCArr.index(of: viewController) else {
        return nil
    }




    let previousIndex = viewControllerIndex-1
    guard previousIndex >= 0  else {
        return nil
    }

    guard VCArr.count > previousIndex else {
        return nil
    }


    return VCArr[previousIndex]
}




public func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?{
    guard let viewControllerIndex = VCArr.index(of: viewController) else {
        return nil
    }

    let nextIndex = viewControllerIndex+1
    guard nextIndex < VCArr.count
        else {
            return nil
    }

    guard VCArr.count > nextIndex else {
        return nil
    }




    return VCArr[nextIndex]
}




 public func presentationCount(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int{
    return VCArr.count

}


 public func presentationIndex(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int{
    guard let firstViewController = viewControllers?.first , let firstViewControllerIndex = VCArr.index(of: firstViewController) else {


        return 0
    }
        let firstIndex = firstViewControllerIndex - 1
        guard firstIndex >= VCArr.count  else {
            return VCArr.count



    }

    return firstViewControllerIndex
}
public func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
    self.pageVC.currentPage = pageViewController.viewControllers!.first!.view.tag

 if(viewControllers!.first?.view.tag == 4 ) {

    if (VCArr.last!.isViewLoaded)

    {

        let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let viewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FivethVC")
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = viewController
        print("It is Done!!!")

    }

    }
}





}
```